# Why is the Action getting changed to Accumulator

Tags: scala, playframework-2.6

I have this action

```
def newQuestion:Action[Either[MaxSizeExceeded,AnyContent]] = silhouette.SecuredAction.async (parse.maxLength(maxAllowedBodySize,parse.anyContent)(materializer)) { ...}
```

Its return type is `Action[Either[MaxSizeExceeded,AnyContent]]`

When I call it in my unit test, the return type changes to `Accumulator[ByteString,Result]`. why?

```
val body:String = """{...}"""
val jsonBody = Json.parse(body)

val request:FakeRequest[AnyContentAsJson] = new FakeRequest(FakeRequest("POST","ws/questions/new-question")).withAuthenticator(testEnv.testEnv.loginInfo)(testEnv.testEnv.fakeEnv).withHeaders(CONTENT_TYPE->"application/json").withBody(AnyContentAsJson(jsonBody))//AnyContentAsJson returns FakeRequest[AnyContentAsJson]
      val request2:FakeRequest[JsValue] = new FakeRequest(FakeRequest("POST","ws/questions/new-question")).withAuthenticator(testEnv.testEnv.loginInfo)(testEnv.testEnv.fakeEnv).withHeaders(CONTENT_TYPE->"application/json").withBody(jsonBody) //Just passinng JsValue to body returns FakeRequest[JsValue]
      val response:Accumulator[ByteString,Result] = testEnv.questionsController.newQuestion(request)//note the return type is Accumulator, not Action
val response2:Accumulator[ByteString,Result] = testEnv.questionsController.newQuestion(request2) //note the return type is Accumulator, not Action
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the `Either[MaxSizeExceeded,AnyContent]` if the input request type, which means that the request you are processing have the value of type `Either[MaxSizeExceeded,AnyContent]` available, look into the official docs:

```
/**
 * An action is essentially a (Request[A] => Result) function that
 * handles a request and generates a result to be sent to the client.
 *
 * For example,
 * {{{
 * val echo = Action { request =>
 *   Ok("Got request [" + request + "]")
 * }
 * }}}
 *
 * @tparam A the type of the request body
 */
```

The `Action[T]` has an `apply` method that takes a request and processes the request to return the `Accumulator[ByteString,Result]`, in your case, you are invoking that `apply` method.

Just update your calls to not invoke the action, from `testEnv.questionsController.newQuestion(request)` to `testEnv.questionsController.newQuestion` and you'll get what you expect.